# Are these two integrands the same?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, greens-function

$$u(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(s)G(x,s)ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)G(x-s)ds$$
I was looking at an example where the integrand was written in the latter way and not the former and I wanted to know if this was simply a universal way of rewriting the integrand.

EDIT: The issue isn't so much why $G(x,s)$ is written by $G(x-s)$, the question more comes from changing $f(s)$ to $f(x)$. I don't know why this is the case.

Comment: $G$ on left side have two variables, on right side one.

Comment: These definitely do not represent the same integral ... for the simple reason that $G$ is being heavily abused here. Is it a function of one variable, as in the second integral? Is it a function of two variables, as in the first? You can't just change it from one to two variables or back so easily.

Comment: @zkutch also $f(s)$ was changed to $f(x)$. There were a couple things that changed around, I just couldn't figure out how

Comment: Judging from the tags, I believe you are asking specifically about Green's functions, and why it is sometimes written as $G(x, s)$ and other times as $G(x-s)$. Is that correct? If so, please clarify by editing the question.

Comment: @PrincessEev It's rather weird how it was done. So, if we go to the table of Green's Functions on the wikipedia page, they're in terms of the spectral and temporal (if any) variables, so how s was implemented was by subtracting s from x in the function. So let's say we have the 1-D wave equation Green Function $G(x,t) = \frac{1}{2c}\Theta(t-|x/c|)$ would be written as $G(x-s,t) = \frac{1}{2c}\Theta(t-|(x-s)/c|)$

Comment: @PrincessEev Technically it's a function of 2 variables, it's just being explicit in saying that we plug in a difference. At least I think that's what it means.

Comment: Please edit your question to add necessary context (that $G$ is a Green's function for some differential operator). The second integral is simply a typo, it should be $f(s)$, not $f(x)$.

Comment: @Peter I see. Thank you! Also thank you for taking the time to answer the question, confusing as it may have been! I had not considered that that part might have been a typo. I will try to contact the author who worked out the example to confirm and reconvene here should I get a response. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first fix notation here. A Green function for a linear differential operator $L$ is any solution of
$$
L G(x, \xi) = \delta(x-\xi)
$$
For example, if $L = \Delta$ is the Laplacian in 3 dimensions, then
$$
G(x, \xi) = -\frac{1}{4 \pi |x-\xi|}
$$
If a Green function $G$ is known, then a solution of $L u = f$ for general $f$ can be obtained by integration:
$$
u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} G(x, \xi) f(\xi) d\xi.
$$

If the differential operator $L$ has *constant coefficients* (e.g. the Laplacian), then one can always find a Green function $G(x,\xi)$ which depends only on $x-\xi$. That is, one can find a function $E$ of one variable such that
$
G(x, \xi) = E(x-\xi)
$
and thus the integral above may be written
$$
u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} E(x-\xi) f(\xi) d\xi.
$$
You may notice that this is precisely the convolution of $E$ and $f$, so you may rewrite this as
$$
u(x) = (E * f)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} E(x-\xi) f(\xi) d\xi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} E(\xi) f(x-\xi) d\xi.
$$
Some authors conflate the two functions $G$ and $E$ and write $G(x, \xi) = G(x-\xi)$, while others consider this an abuse of notation.